# How does readlines() works in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I don't understand how readlines() works in Python, in this case Python 2. Let me explain, I have the following function in a file that I use in other files via "import", like a package.

```
def openFileForReading(filePath):
if not fileExists(filePath):
    print 'The file, ' + filePath + 'does not exist - cannot read it.'
    return ''
else: 
    fileHandle = open(filePath, 'r')
return fileHandle
```

In my new program, I do this:

```
openFileRead = openFileForReading("Orden.txt")
lineList = openFileRead.readlines()
print lineList
```

And the output it gives me is:

```
[]
```

But if I do this, directly in the file, without using my package function, it works:

```
fileHandle = open("Orden.txt", 'r')
lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
print lineList
```

Why if I do this directly it works but if I do by a function of a package, don't?

P.S.: The "Orden.txt" file is not empty, it has two lines:

```
Orden.txt
Line number 1
Line number 2
```

Comment: In the first example, is there an empty file `Orden.txt` in the current directory?

Comment: @JohnGordon No, It's not empty, it has two lines.

Comment: This code should not produce those results.  Either you're mistaken about the file contents, or there's other code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Are you running the code in the same directory in both cases?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm running the code in the same directory. In the same py file, to be exact. Beside that I did something, two print instructions. One for print openFileRead and another for fileHandle, and these are the results: 
print openFileRead
<open file 'Orden.txt', mode 'r' at 0x1038de5d0>
print fileHandle
<open file 'Orden.txt', mode 'r' at 0x1038de780>
The results means that they both are reading the file.

Comment: Edit the question to show us the full program code.  (You've left out the definition for `fileExists()`, so perhaps you've also left out something else that's important.)

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't know what did I do but now it's working.